# How to put month from date in where clause in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table in database which has fields -`(EId,PId,Date,Time)`.

I want to select all the fields from this table where `month < 5`.To be more elaborate I want entries which were entered into the table before `month 5`.

Please help me write this sql query. Thanks :)

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Hint: `month()`, `year()`

Comment: **Hint:** `SELECT MONTH(`Date`)`

Comment: What years do you want to include?

Comment: Thank you all I'll try this and come back to you in 5 min ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MONTH()` and also remember to restrict the year in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE MONTH(Date) < 5 AND YEAR IN (...)
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM timesheet
WHERE MONTH(Date) <= 6 AND YEAR(Date) <=2016

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit here?  What result are you getting?

Comment: Sorry my fault I was not looking the correct database This query is showing me correct result ..Thanks to all :)